# What is the full name of the torturers' guild in "The Book of the New Sun"?

Tags: the-book-of-the-new-sun

I know a longer name is "The Order of the Seekers for Truth and Penitence," but I remember there being an even more formal name mentioned at one point. Something that is like the "The Fraternal and Beneficent...." Or am I misremembering?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might be misremembering.  The omnibus volume of [*The Book of the New Sun*](https://archive.org/details/bookofnewsun00gene/page/916/mode/2up) is available to borrow at the Internet Archive, and it can be searched for text.  The only groups titled "Order" are the "Order of the Seekers for Truth and Penitence" and the "Order of the Journeying Monials of the Conciliator" (a.k.a. the "order of Pelerines").  The Order of the Seekers etc. is also referred to as the "Guild of Torturers," and there are no other groups titled "Guild" in the books.

"Beneficent" and "Fraternal" have no hits at all in the books.  Similar terms like "Benevolent," "Association," "Fraternity," "Loyal" and "Ancient" have no relevant hits.  In fact the only other organization given a capitalized title I've come across is the "Group of Seventeen."